# How to link to developer page from android app

Tags: java, android, google-play

Google recently added "developer page" in Google Play store.  Is there a way to link to this page from an android app?

I am already linking to one of my apps and that works fine.  So I tried to replace the package name with my developer id like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=11111111111111111"));
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

But that did not work.

Thanks

Comment: I just tried this: Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:\"Pub Name, LLC\"")); and it looks like it's finding all apps by a publisher.  Not the same as going to developer page but close enough

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunately isn't currently possible. The best two options you have are to link to the "all apps by a publisher" page that you discovered or to link externally to the browser version using play.google.com

Answer (score -1):

Using market to link to the dev page doesn't seem to work, but through web browser does which will open in market if user allows.

http: //play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=[ developer page ID ]

ref:
https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html